# Mapping Values to 14 categories (Math and permutations stuff)

Tags: php, algorithm, math, permutation

My app has people put 24 groups of 4 statements in order.   In each group of 4 one is the "D" statement, one is the "I" statement, one is the "S" statement, and one is the "C" statement.

So the end result looks something like ['ISCD','CISD','DISC',CISD,'CISD','ISCD'...]  because the are essentially rearranging the 4 letters

In the end, they get a "score" for each letter using the following algorithm.

```
For each of I,S,C and D
  Find the number of times that letter is first and multiply by 3
  Find the number of times that letter is second and multiply by 2
  Find the number of times that letter is third and muliply by 1
  Total it up, and that is the score for that letter
```

The end result is that each letter (I,S,D,C) gets a score from 0 to 72, and there are always 144 total points given out:

[image]

I want to map the results to 14 reports:

```
D
I
S
C
DI
IS
SC
CD
DS
IC
DIS
ISC
SCD
CDI
```

The idea is that if S is dominant, we choose the S report.  If Both D and I are dominant, we choose the DI report.  If none is particularly dominant, we choose the top 3.  (there is no difference between DI and ID  meaning which one is most dominant is irrelevant if they are both high)

So if the scores are D=50, I=48, S=20,C=26 then I want it to choose "DI" since D and I are dominant. There are 24^(4!) possible responses from the user, that I need to map to 14 reports

I understand that I will have to set the thresholds for what "dominant" means, but for starters, I want to assume all possible responses are equally likely, and to map all possible responses to the 14 reports to where each of the 14 reports is equally likely, given random input.

I expect it's 1 to 5 lines of code.  It'll be in php but any language including math or pseudo code should be fine.

**UPDATE:**
I figured out a way to do it in one line of code, but it's not evenly distributed.  here's the php (no dependencies)

```
<?php
$totals=array();
$lets=array('D','I','S','C');
for($j=0;$j<100000;$j++)
{    
    $vals=array('D'=>0,'I'=>0,'S'=>0,'C'=>0);
    for($i=0;$i<24;$i++)
    {
        shuffle($lets);
        $vals[$lets[0]]+=3;
        $vals[$lets[1]]+=2;
        $vals[$lets[2]]+=1;
    }
    $D=$vals['D'];$I=$vals['I'];$S=$vals['S'];$C=$vals['C'];

    //calculate which report
    $reportKey=($D>36?'D':'').($I>36?'I':'').($S>36?'S':'').($C>36?'C':'');

    if(!$reportKey)
        $reportKey="DIS";
    if(isset($totals[$reportKey]))
        $totals[$reportKey]+=1;
    else
        $totals[$reportKey]=1;

    echo $reportKey." $D $I $S $C <br>";
}
echo "<br>";
foreach ($totals as $k=>$v)
    echo "$k: $v<br>";
```

The magic line is

```
$reportKey=($D>36?'D':'').($I>36?'I':'').($S>36?'S':'').($C>36?'C':'');
```

That line says if any value is over 36, include that letter.   the output of the script is like this:

```
SC 35 33 38 38 
IC 33 42 32 37 
DI 44 39 29 32 
...
...
DC 46 21 35 42 
DIS 38 37 40 29 
IC 36 39 28 41 
DS 41 36 42 25 
C 36 34 29 45 
IS 29 41 38 36 
IS 28 46 41 29 
DS 38 33 40 33 
DS 41 33 40 30 

DS: 1444
D: 889
IS: 1466
S: 910
C: 874
SC: 1442
IC: 1467
DI: 1569
ISC: 407
DSC: 386
DIS: 388
DC: 1487
DIC: 396
I: 875
```

As you can see, it automatically split it into 14 categories, but the distribution varies with the 2 letter ones being way more likely.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would be too difficult to do.  What have you tried so far?  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Teepeemm I added an update with sample code

Comment: Were you hoping for a uniform distribution between the 14 categories?  On average, you'd expect 2 to be above 36, and 2 below, which would give a 2 letter one most often.  But we could play around with the concept of "dominant" to get a more uniform distribution.

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more, `shuffle`ing is a good way to test that it works, but probably doesn't model real people all that well.  You won't expect people to alternate between SDIC and CIDS all that much.  So I guess the question becomes: are you happy with "dominant" being defined the way that it is?

Comment: @Teepeemm good insight!  in fact the real way I do "random" results is to pick a "favorite order" at random, then pick a How Likely factor.  So it could pick a favorite order of "SDIC" and then a probability of .3.   So each time I pick a random number, and if it's < .3   then I do the "Favorite order".  So that models real people much better.   However here I figured I should start with mapping all possible inputs to 14 even outputs.  I don't know if it's really reasonable.  what i've done now is just redistribute the  2 letter ones, like if the difference between them is >9, make it 1 letter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively using Haskell e.g. as follows:

```
combinationsOf _ 0 = [[]]
combinationsOf [] _  = []
combinationsOf (x:xs) k  = map (x:) (combinationsOf xs (k-1) ) ++ combinationsOf xs k
```

The results from GHCI:

```
*Main> concatMap (combinationsOf "DISC") [1,2,3]
["D","I","S","C","DI","DS","DC","IS","IC","SC","DIS","DIC","DSC","ISC"]
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood since I don't know Haskell, but it seems you are creating a list of all possible combinations of taking 1,2,or 3 letters from the 4.  You correctly end up with 14 possibilities.  I have already listed those.  What I need is to map all possible SCORES evenly to one of those 14 choices.   So if the scores are D=50, I=48, S=20,C=26 then I want it to choose "DI"  since D and I are dominant.   There are 24^(4!)  possible responses from the user, that I need to map to 14 reports

Comment: I couldn't remember what your question was like exactly before your update of the question, and I probably misunderstood your question. I think it might be easier if you could make clear what the question is by creating a smaller example than the current one. One small enough that you can enumerate the end-result by hand.